# “libmtp error: Could not get file from device.” on attempting to transfer files from Android phone

Tags: 18.04, permissions, android

I am facing the same problem when I am creating new partition on Ubuntu.
I have not found any exact solution. Now I am resolving my problem.

In my case, the partition does not have proper permissions to access and change the data. There is the permission issue so that I am faced with the

> libmtp error: Could not get file from device.

So the solution is very simple:
give the permission to the partition to access and delete the data.
Here are the steps that I used to solve the problem:

1. Open the terminal press: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>
2. Type:

   ```
   sudo chmod 777 /media/<username>/<your partition name>
   ```

   e.g.

   ```
   sudo chmod 777 /media/shubh/3bsdsdwewewrw31ar
   ```
3. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Now, again, copy the file from the Android device and paste it to your destination. I think that this time it will solve the problem. If the permissions were successfully added, you would directly create a new folder using the GUI.